# A cycle was detected in a LINQ expression exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I get the error :

> A cycle was detected in a LINQ expression.

in `ToList()` while trying to do the following:

```
private IEnumerable<int> FilterIdsByClient(IEnumerable<int> entityIds)
{
    entityIds =
        MyObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>()
            .Where(x => x.ClientId == _clientId)
            .Where(x => entityIds.Contains(x.Id))
            .Select(x => x.Id);

    return entityIds.ToList();
}
```

This however doesn't throw any exception and works fine:

```
private IEnumerable<int> FilterIdsByClient(IEnumerable<int> entityIds)
{
    entityIds =
        MyObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>()
            .Where(x => x.ClientId == _clientId)
            .Where(x => entityIds.Contains(x.Id))
            .Select(x => x.Id)
            .ToList();

    return entityIds;
}
```

(This is a simplfied version of course).

Anyone have a clue why this strange behavior happens?

Edit:

This is the stack trace:

```
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.Funcletize(Expression expression, Func`1& recompileRequired)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.InlineExpression(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.InlineObjectQuery(ObjectQuery inlineQuery, Type expressionType)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.InlineValue(Expression expression, Boolean recompileOnChange)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 original)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda(LambdaExpression lambda)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression u)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 original)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitExpressionList(ReadOnlyCollection`1 original)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.EntityExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.FuncletizingVisitor.Visit(Expression exp)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.Funcletizer.Funcletize(Expression expression, Func`1& recompileRequired)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter..ctor(Funcletizer funcletizer, Expression expression)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.CreateExpressionConverter()
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at ...FilterIdsByClient...
```

Edit2:

Should note that in this case, `IEnumerable<int> entityIds` is a list comming from an ajax request and not a query from somewhere.

Comment: Can you try resolve results of `MyObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>()` in to a variable and then use it in LINQ query ?

Comment: But this will return the table from the DB, wouldn't it? And also, how is this going to help ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The behavior seems strange because you are not considering the closure semantics correctly.  See the comments below:

```
private IEnumerable<int> FilterIdsByClient(IEnumerable<int> entityIds) 
{ 
    // The variable entityIds points to whatever was passed in: A List, according to the edited question.

    entityIds =                                    //this is an assignment, changing the referent of entityIds
        MyObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>() 
            .Where(x => x.ClientId == _clientId) 
            .Where(x => entityIds.Contains(x.Id))  //this lambda closes over the variable entityIds
            .Select(x => x.Id); 

    // The query now has a reference to the *variable* entityIds, not to the object that entityIds pointed to originally.
    // The value of entityIds has been changed; it now points to the query itself!
    // The query is therefore operating on itself; this causes the "cycle detected" message.
    // Because of delayed execution, the query is not executed until the next line of code:

    return entityIds.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Why are you assigning to your parameter? Why not

```
private IEnumerable<int> FilterIdsByClient(IEnumerable<int> entityIds) 
{ 
    return
        MyObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>() 
            .Where(x => x.ClientId == _clientId) 
            .Where(x => entityIds.Contains(x.Id)) 
            .Select(x => x.Id)
            .ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: This wasn't my question. I know I can do that and I agree this is better but I wanted to know WHY this behavior happens.

Comment: Sure, just wanted to point out that assigning the way you do is asking for trouble, period. The explanation is pretty simple: you're assigning an enumerator that uses the original value of the one you're assigning to as phoog explains.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is to not assign the LINQ query to `entityIds`. See @Stu's answer for a solution.

Comment: Note that entityIds is a list and not a query. What do you mean by rewriting it? How ?

Comment: @gil: actually, entityIds is a variable. In the exception-raising code example, at the .ToList() call, that variable has been reassigned and points to the query, not the list.

Comment: In your first example, it isn't a list, but a LINQ query. This is that the error explains. However, in the second example, the output of `ToList` is assigned to `entityIds` **after** the query is run, so `entityIds` will be `null`. Concerning how to rewrite it: I couldn't help you with this because this depends n what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Pieter: You mean by reassigning the query to entityIds, I made a recursion-like query! Very interesting. Thank you.

Comment: @Pieter: There is no `null` involved in this problem.  Rather, entityIds will point to a WhereIterator or a SelectIterator (or similar) that references itself (directly or indirectly) through the closure over the variable entityIds.  That's why you get a cycle error rather than a NullReferenceException.

Comment: Why is this getting upvotes?  The analysis of the problem is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

Of course there is a cycle. You are using entityIds in the Where Linq Extension method and it is the query being constructed itself. Instead of modifying the inputted IEnumerable, return a new query as follows:

```
private IEnumerable<int> FilterIdsByClient(IEnumerable<int> entityIds)
{
    var query =
        MyObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>()
            .Where(x => x.ClientId == _clientId)
            .Where(x => entityIds.Contains(x.Id))
            .Select(x => x.Id);

    return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: But entityIds is just a list. NOT a query.

Comment: @gil: actually, entityIds is a *variable*.  In the exception-raising code example, at the `.ToList()` call, that variable *has been reassigned* and points to the query, not the list.

Comment: @gil See phoog's answer. You will benefit much if you understand that Linq expressions use lambdas that have closures and therefore there are intricacies involved.