# A cycle in LINQ expression

Tags: linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A cycle was detected in a LINQ expression exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8658278/a-cycle-was-detected-in-a-linq-expression-exception)

I have a small problem. I have 2 IQueryable (A and B). I want to find the complement numbers. For this i use Except: `A.Except(B)`

This will give me all the number in A that ARE NOT in B.

This works. My problem is that i want to do this `A = A.Except(B)`
But this leaves me with an ERROR:

```
A cycle was detected in a LINQ expression exception
```

Anyone got a suggestion on how I could solve this.
I can't just create a new IQueryable C to hold the A.Except(B) result. Because I need A repediatly in later code.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a duplicate, but it's certainly related.

Comment: `A` can't be both `A` and `A.Except(B)`

Answer (score 4):

Just create an intermediate list which you use to store your result.

```
var C = A.Except(B).ToArray();
```

`C` will hold your desired result, while `A` and `B` will remain unchanged.

Comment: might be more meaningful to call `C` `aExceptB` but I agree.